# How to wrangle complex survey data before ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, survey

Hoping to understand a little bit more about svy objects in terms of data wrangling that is piped into visualizations.

```
data %>%    
    filter(response != "Never") %>% 
    group_by(item, response) %>%
    tally() %>% 
    mutate(response_total = n, #number of each kind of response
           perc = n/12619 #total number of responses
              ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = item, y = perc, fill = response)) +
    geom_col()
```

This wrangling removes the psu, strata, and upm from the data frame – so I can no longer use survey::svydesign(). Is there a way to create the svy object (to ensure the survey weights and such are included) and then perform wrangling on the data before visualization?

Comment: I do not see a step that would remove those variables. I recommend to trouble-shoot each line of code by temporarily piping to `head()`, to print the first 5 rows of your dataframe at that step. Start with the data line of code `data %>% head()`; then move the `head()` to after the pipe on the `filter()` row. etc.

Comment: Thanks for this – it looks like tally() is where the rest of the data is removed – not sure how else to calculate the n needed for the new variables within the following mutate()? Having trouble with count() in this case.

Comment: Yes, I see tally is summarizing the groups (and drops the non-grouped fields).  Try `add_tally()` which adds the group count to each row.

Comment: hi, are you looking for something like this?  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/srvyr/vignettes/srvyr-vs-survey.html

Comment: Greetings! It would be helpful to have a minimal reproducible dataset included in your question. One way of doing that is by using the `dput` command. You can find out how to do this here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg